# How to reset scroll position of modal in bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a [bootstrap v3 modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), like in the documentation.

When I open the modal for a first time ('Launch demo model' button) a vertical scroll bar is in a top position. If I scroll down and click 'Cancel' in modal it will close. It is ok. But if I open modal again it will be already scrolled down. And this is case which I would like to avoid. What should I do to open modal in a top position?

Answer (score 5):

## working in production

```
$('#my-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#my-modal').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Correct event name should be "shown.bs.modal" or "hide.bs.modal". My preference would be the latter.

Comment: This is just "bs" anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to to use the events that fire when the modal is opened to reset the scrolling.

Something like:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Depending on your page you might wantto use some jQuery or animations:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#myModal").offset().top
 }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I have tried to use 'shown.bs.modal' event. It fires right, but windows.scrollTo has no effect on modal. Instead of this, it scrolls main windows (on background).

Comment: even though it's a very old post, I comment here maybe it helps somebody.
you have to add `.modal` to selectors list , so instead of ` $('html, body')` it would be ` $('html, body, .modal')` or remove `html` and `body` .
 modal content will scroll too

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by setting a focus on the top input element om my modal:

```
    $("#RuleDialog").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#LinkedRuleName').focus();
    });
```

Comment: This is not a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 modal

```
$modal.off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    if ($modal.scrollTop() > 0) {
        $modal.scrollTop(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got this functionality working . First set up the shown event of the modal .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var modalMatrix = $('#modalMatrix');
    modalMatrix.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        modalMatrix.find('.modal-body').scrollTop(0); // This is important , for me the scrollbar is in the body of the modal .
    });
});
```

Then I show the modal , as usual .

```
$('#modalMatrix').modal('show');
```